# How to route all packets through Windows web server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, routing, rras

I have the following sitiuation I have dedicated server with IP `85.25.148.23/255.255.255.0` GW `85.25.148.1` running windows web server 2008

I installed VMware on it having linux centos OS I found a limitition on my datacenter that it only accepts traffic from the dedicated server MAC address

now I need to get over this by routing to `85.25.250.21/255.255.255.192` through the `85.25.148.23`, so the MAC still the same as dedicated server

I did this before using Linux dedicated, now I need to do the same with windows WEB server 2008.

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but Windows Server 2008 Web is *very* restrictive in what you can do with it, so I don't know how much success you'll have with any built-in Windows functionality.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on how you are using this the CentOS VM if this will work for you are not. But the simplest solution would just be to tell the VMWare VM to use "NAT (Network address translation)" and then all requests coming from that that machine would like they are coming from the .23 machines IP and MAC address (I believe anyways -- would be strange if it wasn't IMO).

Less simple, but still possible would be to configure your Web server as a router. With this, you would use the "Routing and Remote Access Services".

Lastly, I imagine the reason they have this policy is that they want you to be using a router / firewall device as the gateway for all of your servers and services. IF you can't convince them otherwise, your best bet is probably just to give in an set up something like pfsense as a router or get a basic Cisco router or ASA device.

Comment: about the NAT, ok I accept the solution, I tried to use the ICS and VMWARE nat, but all was forwarding all traffic from the internet to the VM, while I cant set the DMZ for a specific IP to the VM, do you have a way to define the virtual ports on 1 IP instead of all physical Server IPs?